# Getting an error while running PowerShell with TFS 2010

Tags: powershell

Given this simple script:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")

$serverName="http://server:8080/tfs/Collection"
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)
$buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])

$buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("Project") | foreach {
  echo "Found build: $_.Name"
}
```

What would be the reason to get this error:

```
Exception calling "QueryBuildDefinitions" with "1" argument(s): "Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.HandleUnauthorizedException(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServer
UnauthorizedException)'."
At C:\DevOps\TfsClient\Test.ps1:8 char:35
+ $buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions <<<< ("Project") | foreach {
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException


$buildserver | Get-Member -Name QueryBuildDefinitions

   TypeName: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.BuildServer

Name                  MemberType Definition                                                                                                                                                                                        
----                  ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                                                        
QueryBuildDefinitions Method     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildDefinition[] QueryBuildDefinitions(string teamProject), Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildDefinition[] QueryBuildDefinitions(string teamP...
```

Comment: The unauthorized part might be something. Are you running with an account that has appropriate permissions? I would check the version of the libraries as well to make sure that you are loading the version of tfs objects you think you are.

Comment: `$buildServer | Get-Member` lists `QueryBuildDefinitions(string teamProject)`

Comment: The UnauthorizedException is suspect. Does it fail when you impersonate? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2010/11/04/using-the-new-tfs-2010-impersonation-apis.aspx